# Cannot Open Devcon

Tags: driver, wdk

I installed WinDDK 7600 in my Windows XP operating  system.Now,when I double click the devcon.exe(Location- D:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\devcon\i386),the command prompt is just showing up and suddenly disappears.Can anyone resolve this issue.

Comment: Rather than double clicking it, open up a `cmd` prompt and run it from there.  It may need some switches specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware devcon is a command-line only program. You have to run it from a command window (cmd.exe) with the appropriate parameters. Once you know the parameters you want to use, you can write a batch file to easily recreate the command you want.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post because Win7 has a similar problem even when running in cmd.exe.

There is a solution found on Microsofts website here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/devcon-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7/9abcc12c-d7db-4249-aec4-fc4ff0ea6ee8

I have not been able to verify it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The same (a windows open and automatically close) happens even if using a normal command prompt. However opening the command prompt with administrator rights and then run devcon works.